# delete sql tables refering each other

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, each referring the other (created by django ORM).
Each table references the other table.

Now I want to write a script that deletes all tables, but I'm failing to do so since I get foreign key violation 
I'm doing

```
mysql> delete from table1
mysql> delete from table2
```

I know I can ignore the checks, but the problem is that these checks were generated by django with cryptic names

thanks.

Comment: Is the FK column nullable in either? If it is, first `UPDATE` all rows to `NULL` then drop the table.

Comment: Post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Or, Shouldn't `DELETE` with `JOIN` will work fine, since MySQL supports this?

Comment: But why can you not ignore with `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;`? You don't need to know the constraint names for that.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Yes, that should be possible as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this -

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

DELETE FROM table1;
DELETE FROM table2;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Documentation: [foreign_key_checks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks).